# While running a flex template NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn is thrown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am running gcp flex templates in dataflow.

While starting a job from a template I am getting this exception:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class. 
com.mycompany.pubsubdfjobs.protocol1_0.PubSubRedis
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn

DoFn is used in a lot of classes in the Project. I am able to run the code locally. All dependencies are in my gradle.build file. The gradle.build file is copied to the Dokerfile the is used for the template.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your `JAR` is not able to find the main class for your project. This class should be specified on your pom.xml file according to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/#self-executing-jar). This file needs to have the same structure as the sample presented in the documentation. You can make sure that the `plugin` tag on your `pom.xml` file matches the one found in the documentation.